# sed command is not working in userdata of ubuntu ec2

Tags: tomcat, sed, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04, aws-cloudformation

I want to replace a line in `apache-tomcat-7.0.50/conf/server.xml` via template in my ubuntu ec2 instance.I used the following command but its not working.

```
#!/bin/sh -v
/usr/bin/apt-get update -y
/usr/bin/apt-get upgrade -y
sed -i 's/proxyName=.*/proxyName=elburl proxyPort=\"80\"\/>/' /home/ubuntu/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/conf/server.xml
service tomcat restart
```

But I am able to run sed command in command prompt.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please format your script. Is this how your script look? ( mean `\n`,`"` in end of each line).

Answer (score 0):

`sed -i 's#proxyName=.*/proxyName=elburl proxyPort=\"80\"\#>#' /home/ubuntu/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/conf/server.xml`

use another (here i use `#`) separator than default `/` because you use it inside your pattern (or escape it in your pattern)